# ASP.net Webforms to MVC Migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, migration

I am looking for a way to start the migration of asp.net webforms to an asp.net MVC project that allows the webform pages to be used, but keeps things clean for the new mvc structure.  Many of the solutions I have seen for this involve converting the existing webforms project to a web application project and adding in the MVC reference.  While this solution should I work, I am concerned that doing things this way will make things chaotic since the directory structures will be different for asp.net webforms vs. asp.net mvc and overall just make things messy/difficult to deal with.

The ideal solution would be to have two projects (the legacy webforms project and a new mvc project) where any new pages would be in the mvc project and legacy pages in the webforms project.  Is there anyway that this can be done or any other options that will keep things clean for the asp.net mvc structure?

Comment: Is the goal to host both flavors as a single site or are you wanting to leverage business objects, repositories, etc. between the two flavors of UI?

Comment: The goal would be to host both flavors as a single site.

Comment: If your web forms project is web site template, you have to convert to web app template.  We have a combo web form/MVC app that I am working with currently, and the web forms are in the root folder, and MVC in the normal folder structure.  It's not that bad to have combined.

Comment: Well, at least you need to set page routing on new project pointed to legacy project using `MapPageRoute`. Since converting existing webforms to MVC may take some time and effort for removing server control instances, it is acceptable to keep webforms project inside a separate directory and then configuring related links in MVC.